# Using <collection> in MyBatis3 gives NULL for list of items

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to use the `<collection>` in **MyBatis3**. However, all the items that form the part of the `List/collection` are always NULL.

Here is what my SQL is -

```sql
<select id="fetchPaymentWorkingALL" resultType="paymentWorkingALL" parameterType="java.util.Map">
    select
        (person_id + '-' + convert(char(10), end_date, 126) + '-' + company + '-' + plan) as paymentid
         ,person_id as personid
         ,(person_id + '-' + convert(char(10), end_date, 126) + '-' + company + '-' + plan + '-' + 'non_mid_year') as otherid
         ,'non_mid_year' as typename
         ,'0' as typeid
         ,sum(amount) as amount
         ,sum(return1_amount) + sum(return2_amount) as returnamount
         ,sum(endamount) as endamount
    from #ABCD
    group by person_id, income_type, end_date, company, plan, plan_id
</select>
```

The output of the query looks like this -

```
paymentid                        | personid    | otherid                                       | typename        | typeid  |     amount        | returnamount  | endamount
---------------------------------|-------------|-----------------------------------------------|-----------------|---------|-------------------|---------------|------------------
3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-non_mid_year   | non_mid_year    |    0    |    10000.0000     | 1200.0000     | 11200.0000
3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-total          | total           |    2    |    10000.0000     | 1200.0000     | 11200.0000
3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-mid_year       | mid_year        |    1    |    15000.0000     | 1150.0000     | 16150.0000
3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-non_mid_year   | non_mid_year    |    0    |    10000.0000     | 1200.0000     | 11200.0000
3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-total          | total           |    2    |    25000.0000     | 2350.0000     | 27350.0000
3520-2019-12-31-EFGH-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2019-12-31-EFGH-Mandatory-non_mid_year   | non_mid_year    |    0    |    10000.0000     | 1200.0000     | 11200.0000
3520-2019-12-31-EFGH-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2019-12-31-EFGH-Mandatory-total          | total           |    2    |    10000.0000     | 1200.0000     | 11200.0000
3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-mid_year       | mid_year        |    1    |    15000.0000     | 1150.0000     | 16150.0000
3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-non_mid_year   | non_mid_year    |    0    |    10000.0000     | 1200.0000     | 11200.0000
3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-total          | total           |    2    |    25000.0000     | 2350.0000     | 27350.0000
3520-2020-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2020-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-mid_year       | mid_year        |    1    |    15000.0000     | 1150.0000     | 16150.0000
3520-2020-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory   | 3520        | 3520-2020-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-total          | total           |    2    |    15000.0000     | 1150.0000     | 16150.0000
```

The `resultMaps` look like so -

```xml
<resultMap id="paymentWorkingALL" type="PaymentWorkingALL">
    <id property="paymentid" column="paymentid" />
    <result property="personid" column="personid" />
    <collection property="paymentWorkings"
        ofType="PaymentWorking"
        resultMap="paymentWorkingMap" />

</resultMap>

<resultMap id="paymentWorkingMap" type="PaymentWorking">
    <id property="otherid" column="otherid" />
    <result property="typename" column="typename"/>
    <result property="typeid" column="typeid"/>
    <result property="amount" column="amount"/>
    <result property="endamount" column="endamount"/>
    <result property="returnamount" column="returnamount"/>
</resultMap>
```

I have also added the aliases like so -

```xml
<typeAlias type="com.abcd.PaymentWorkingALL" alias="PaymentWorkingALL"/>
<typeAlias type="com.abcd.PaymentWorking" alias="PaymentWorking"/>
```

and my classes look like so -

```java
public class PaymentWorkingALL {

    private String paymentid;
    private String personid;
    private List<PaymentWorking> paymentWorkings;

    public String getPaymentid() {
        return paymentid;
    }

    public void setPaymentid(String paymentid) {
        this.paymentid = paymentid;
    }

    public String getPersonid() {
        return personid;
    }

    public void setPersonid(String personid) {
        this.personid = personid;
    }

    public List<PaymentWorking> getPaymentWorkings() {
        return paymentWorkings;
    }

    public void setPaymentWorkings(List<PaymentWorking> paymentWorkings) {
        this.paymentWorkings = paymentWorkings;
    }
}
```

```java
public class PaymentWorking {

    private String otherid;
    private String typename;
    private String typeid;
    private Double amount;
    private Double returnamount;
    private Double endamount;

    public String getOtherid() {
        return otherid;
    }

    public void setOtherid(String otherid) {
        this.otherid = otherid;
    }

    public String getTypename() {
        return typename;
    }

    public void setTypename(String typename) {
        this.typename = typename;
    }

    public String getTypeid() {
        return typeid;
    }

    public void setTypeid(String typeid) {
        this.typeid = typeid;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Double getReturnamount() {
        return returnamount;
    }

    public void setReturnamount(Double returnamount) {
        this.returnamount = returnamount;
    }

    public Double getEndamount() {
        return endamount;
    }

    public void setEndamount(Double endamount) {
        this.endamount = endamount;
    }
}
```

---

My expectation was that I would get an List which would look like this -

```
[
  {
    "paymentid": "3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory",
    "personid": "3520",
    "paymentWorkings": [
      {
        "otherid": "3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-non_mid_year",
        "typename": "non_mid_year",
        "typeid": "0",
        "amount": 10000.00,
        "returnamount": 1200.00,
        "endamount": 11200.00      
      },
      {
        "otherid": "3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-total",
        "typename": "total",
        "typeid": "2",
        "amount": 10000.00,
        "returnamount": 1200.00,
        "endamount": 11200.00      
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paymentid": "3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory",
    "personid": "3520",
    "paymentWorkings": [
      {
        "otherid": "3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-non_mid_year",
        "typename": "non_mid_year",
        "typeid": "0",
        "amount": 10000.00,
        "returnamount": 1200.00,
        "endamount": 11200.00      
      },
      {
        "otherid": "3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-mid_year",
        "typename": "mid_year",
        "typeid": "1",
        "amount": 15000.00,
        "returnamount": 1150.00,
        "endamount": 16150.00      
      },
      {
        "otherid": "3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory-total",
        "typename": "total",
        "typeid": "2",
        "amount": 25000.00,
        "returnamount": 2350.00,
        "endamount": 27350.00      
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, when the query runs, I get a `List<PaymentWorkingALL>` with size as **12** and each having `paymentWorkings` as `NULL`.

As per my understanding, it should have returned a `List<PaymentWorkingALL>` of length **5** and their IDs would be one of -

```
'3520-2017-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory',
'3520-2018-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory',
'3520-2019-12-31-EFGH-Mandatory',
'3520-2019-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory',
'3520-2020-12-31-ABCD-Mandatory'
```

---

I am using the following versions of mybatis and mybatis-spring -

```
<mybatis.version>3.2.3</mybatis.version>
<mybatis.spring.version>1.2.0</mybatis.spring.version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paymentWorkingALL` result map is not used because you haven't instruct mybatis to use it, so it has two consequences:

1. mybatis does not know what is the `id` field of the `PaymentWorkingALL` and treats all rows as unique objects (hence 12 objects in the result)
2. `paymentWorkings` association is not mapped at all (so objects are not created in the collection)

To fix this specify result map as the attribute of the `select` node like this:

```
<select id="fetchPaymentWorkingALL" resultMap="paymentWorkingALL" parameterType="java.util.Map">
 ...
</select>
```

Comment: Adding a `resultMap` instead of a `resultType` worked.